# Trouble printing an array of strings after realloc?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, split, c-strings

The code below reads characters and splits them into C-style strings when a delimiter is encountered, then it stores the words (white-space-separated sequences of characters) in string array till a sentinel is encountered; updates size of string array:

```
#include <stdio.h>      // printf()
#include <stdlib.h>     // malloc(); realloc()
#include <string.h>     // strcmp()
#include <stddef.h>     // size_t

void print_array(char* arr[ ], size_t size); // forward declaration to use in to_array()

char* get_word(char delimiter)
{
    size_t size = 8;
    size_t index = 0;

    int c = 0;
    char* word = 0;
    char* expand_word = 0;

    word = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * size);
    if (word == NULL)
    {
        perror("get_word::bad malloc!\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != delimiter && c != '\n')
    {
        if (index >= size)
        {
            size *= 2;

            expand_word = (char*) realloc(word, sizeof(char) * size);
            if (expand_word == NULL)
            {
                perror("get_word::bad realloc!\n");
                exit(-1);
            }

            word = expand_word;
        } 

        word[index++] = c;
    }

    word[index] = 0;

    return word;
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void to_array(char* arr[ ], size_t* size, char* sentinel)
{
    size_t index = 0;
    char* word = 0;
    char** expand_arr = 0;
    char delimiter = ' ';

    while ((word = get_word(delimiter)) && strcmp(word, sentinel) != 0)
    {
        if (index >= (*size))
        {
            (*size) *= 2;

            expand_arr = (char**) realloc(arr, sizeof(char*) * (*size));
            if (expand_arr == NULL)
            {
                perror("to_array::bad realloc!\n");
                exit(-1);
            }  

            arr = expand_arr;
        }

        arr[index++] = word;
    }

    (*size)  = index;

    // print_array(arr, *size); // <---- here, all words printed OK.
    // getchar();
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

void print_array(char* arr[ ], size_t size)
{
    size_t i = 0;

    printf("{ ");
    for (i; i < size; ++i)
    {
        printf("%s", arr[i]);

        if (i < size - 1)
        {
            printf(", ");
        }
    }
    printf(" }\n");
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

int main()
{
    size_t size = 4;
    char** arr = 0;
    char* sentinel = "quit";

    arr = (char**) malloc(sizeof(char*) * size);
    if (arr == NULL)
    {
        perror("array of strings::bad malloc!\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    printf("Type a sentence and get each word as an array element:\n");
    to_array(arr, &size, sentinel);

    printf("Words:\n");
    print_array(arr, size);   // <--------- here, error!

    getchar();
}
```

When trying to print the string array, I get:

> `Access violation reading location 0xcd007361.`

Why I can't print the strings in `arr` at the end?

---

<sup>P.S.: I guess that the problem comes from the pointer arithmetic and the reallocation of the `char** arr` within function `to_array()`. (If previous right) I'm not sure what would be the standard way to deal with it?</sup>

Comment: `arr` doesn't change outside your function. That's a classic. So when location changes (realloc does that when it cannot avoid it) your printf doesn't follow.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I understand, thank you! I already tried passing something like `char*** arr`, instead of `char* arr[]` (in `to_array()`), but that doesn't seems to work either. What should be done here, return `arr` from `to_array()`?

Comment: you need `**arr[]` and `*arr = realloc`. Returning `arr` is a better option IMHO.

Comment: @Ziezi need to have three levels of indirection usually points towards bad design. It would be better if you return `arr` or restructure code.

Comment: did you solve your exercice ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Problem:

the first parameter in `void to_array()`, i.e. `char* arr[ ]` passes a copy of a pointer to array of `char`. Every change on the pointer made inside the function does not affect the actual pointer to `char` array outside, specifically the function `realloc()` may move the initial memory block to a new location, which would invalidate the pointer passed as first parameter.

### Solution:

either to modify the function `void to_array()` to return the modified `arr`, or to modify the first parameter of the function to `char** arr[ ]`. The latter was chosen and the modified code looks like this:

```
void to_array(char** arr[ ], size_t* size, char* quit)
{
    size_t index = 0;
    char* word = 0;
    char** expand_arr = 0;
    char sentinel = ' ';

    while ((word = get_word(sentinel)) && strcmp(word, quit) != 0)
    {
       if (index >= (*size))
       {
           (*size) *= 2;

           expand_arr = (char**) realloc((*arr), sizeof(char*) * (*size));

           if (expand_arr == NULL)
           {
                perror("to_array::bad realloc!\n");
               exit(-1);
           }

           (*arr) = expand_arr;
        }

        (*arr)[index++] = word;
    }  

    (*size)  = index;
}
```

then the function call must be done as:

```
to_array(&arr, &size, quit);
```